# Proving the closed-formed formula of a recursive expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction, closed-form

I was given this exercise as a practice for discrete mathematics, among some others. The instruction is to provide a closed-form formula for the recursive formula shown below.

$u_n =2 + \sum_{i=1}^s 2^t*u_i $

where $s=n-1$ and $t=n-2i$.

We are asked to prove the closed-formed formula we suggested by induction. I have encountered trouble in my efforts, since, though I can prove my formula is true for a base case, and then assume it is true for *k*, I can't seem to prove it's true for *k+1*.
We are told (a) $u_n$ is true for all n>1, (b) $u_1=2$

By evauluation,

$u_2= 2 + 1*2 = 4$ and $u_3 = 2+2^*u_1+\frac12*u_2=2+2*2+\frac12*4=6+2=8$

Being $u_1=2$

$u_2 = 4$

$u_3=8$

I suggested the formula

$u_n=2^n$, so that

$$u_n =2 + \sum_{i=1}^s 2^t*u_i =2^n$$

As I said, I failed to prove this by induction. Is anybody out there able to point my error out, or show how can I prove this by induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $u_i = 2^i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n-1$, then

$$u_n = 2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 2^{n-2i} u_i = 2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 2^{n-2i} 2^i = 2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 2^{n-i} =$$

$$ =2+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}2^j = 2 + \frac{1-2^n}{1-2} - 1 = 2^n$$

Comment: Hello, dcolazin. First of all, thank you for answering my question. I got a bit lost when you changed i = 1 by j = 1 on the summation, and the stepts after that. Could you clarify them for me? I'm very sorry I'm not able to keep up with your explanation, I have started learning maths only very recently. Thank you!

Comment: What he wrote is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}2^{n-i}&=2+2^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}2^{-i}=2+2^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i}\\
&=2+2^{n}\left(\frac{2^{n}-2}{2^{n}}\right)=2+2^{n}-2\\
&=2^{n}.
\end{align*}

Comment: @Jake, thank you for answering.

Could you clarify what are you doing when you are replacing the summatory by that fraction, and why is this valid?

Comment: @AngelusSilesius, notice that the summation is a geometric sum. I replaced it with the formula for a finite geometric sum.

Comment: @Jake, not only clear but also beautiful. Thank you both for answering my question in the first place, and thank you Jake for clarifying what I couldn't grasp!